# How can I checkout from tag on PyCharm?

Tags: pycharm

I would like to checkout a repository with specifying tag on PyCharm.
Do you guys know how is enable to do that?

Answer (score 0):

It is in `VCS -> Git -> Branches`. This menu is practically `git checkout`. For that modal windows, you have the list of branches, but you can also use tags or revisions.

Or in git view (bottom tab on main PyCharm windows), you can navigate history, and checkout a precise point. You see also the tags (and you can search tags, with name, regex, etc.).

But I do not know any way to get just a list of tags, to select. I eventually use console, but it is not on my normal workflow, so I do not know if there is an explicit method in PyCharm. I use common tag names (vX.Y), so easy to remember and to type.

Comment: Thank you. Yeah, I will use console for checking out with tag.